# Implications of setting "usershare owner only = false" in smb.conf

Tags: wubi, configuration, samba

I'm using Wubi and want to share a directory from the (Win8) host via Samba. When I try to do this using Nautilus I receive the following error:

> 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot share path /host/path as we are restricted to only sharing directories we own.
>
> Ask the administrator to add the line "usershare owner only = false" to the [global] section of the smb.conf to allow this.

Are there any negative implications to adding this line?

Comment: This might help [Solved: How to change file permissions of host in Wubi?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657964)

Comment: I think you are asking if there is any negative implication to adding the line "usershare owner only = false" and not asking how to share folders we don't own over SMB. If I am right, then I suggest you to change the title to be more clear and get more answers. Regards.

Comment: @desgua, you're right. The question evolved as I was writing it :)